# HmacSHA256 Signature Doesn't Match Expected Signature

Tags: python, python-3.x, digital-signature, sha256, hmac

I'm following [this docs](https://bingx-api.github.io/docs/swap/authentication.html#signature) and I can't find a way of creating the right HmacSHA256 signature using Python. Based on the docs, the request signature should come from doing: `HmacSHA256 (originString)`. There is an example of the result that looks like this:

```
Signature = HmacSHA256("UuGuyEGt6ZEkpUObCYCmIfh0elYsZVh80jlYwpJuRZEw70t6vomMH7Sjmf94ztSI", "POST/api/v1/user/getBalanceapiKey=Zsm4DcrHBTewmVaElrdwA67PmivPv6VDK6JAkiECZ9QfcUnmn67qjCOgvRuZVOzU&currency=USDT&timestamp=1615272721001")
```

With `Signature` being `xi0uYQFvJaMxd1bMVPb0PxSw2Rz46Q1olKzM6mzVu18%3D`.

I'm trying to reproduce this result with Python, I'm not getting the same result but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong:

```
def generate_signature(key, message):
    '''
    Signature = HmacSHA256(secretkey, originString)
    '''

    signature = hmac.new(key.encode(), message.encode(), hashlib.sha256).digest()
    signature = base64.b64encode(signature)
    signature = urllib.parse.quote_plus(signature)
    return signature
```

Passing to this function the example above I'm getting this:

```
generate_signature("UuGuyEGt6ZEkpUObCYCmIfh0elYsZVh80jlYwpJuRZEw70t6vomMH7Sjmf94ztSI", "POST/api/v1/user/getBalanceapiKey=Zsm4DcrHBTewmVaElrdwA67PmivPv6VDK6JAkiECZ9QfcUnmn67qjCOgvRuZVOzU&currency=USDT&timestamp=1615272721001")
# ZLDEpF7hj%2BzW8Cnvfus%2BVsRBK690iZwPI%2BOlYfH%2BHR4%3D
```

Which is a different result from the expected based on the docs, any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: the original signature (xi0uYQFvJaM...) is base64 encoded, but the python function creates a hex encoded output (64b0c4a45ee18fecd6...) with `.hexdigest()`.

Comment: @jps Adding a base64 encoding to the signature returns `ZLDEpF7hj%2BzW8Cnvfus%2BVsRBK690iZwPI%2BOlYfH%2BHR4%3D` which is still different from the expected, I'm updating the question.

Comment: Another thing is the parameter `key`, which looks like a base64 encoded string. Maybe it is supposed to be decoded.

Comment: Nice point, I didn't think about that. I just tried passing `base64.b64decode(key)` when creating the hash, now it's returning `sYLrI41NUqvGsFpdjb%2BFa505Wj7T9ED5WSrxUe50%2FyA%3D`.

Comment: I get the same values you get, I can't get it to work.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk thanks for trying, I'll contact support in case they have it wrong in their docs.